# Counting the number of occurrences of characters in an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

This is what I have but it is not working, this is confusing for me. If you scroll down I commented on someones post the exact problem I am having and what I am trying to do. I was thinking maybe the problem is my code to generate the random characters:

```
public void add (char fromChar, char toChar){
    Random r = new Random(); //creates a random object
    int randInt;
    for (int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++){
        randInt = r.nextInt((toChar-fromChar) +1);
        charArray[i] = (char) randInt; //casts these integers as characters
    }
}//end add
public int[] countLetters() {
int[] count = new int[26];
char current;

     for (int b = 0; b <= 26; b++) {
         for (int i = 97; i <= 123; i++) {
             char a = (char) i;
             for (int ch = 0; ch < charArray.length; ch++) {
                 current = charArray[ch];
                if (current == a) {
                count[b]++;
                }
             }
         }
     }
return count;
}
```

Comment: Why isn't it working? What happens?

Comment: The best way is to sort your array first and scan the array to check if there is a duplicate and increment the count .

Comment: We can guess from your code that you are trying to store the number of a's in count[0], the number of b's in count[1], the number of c's in count[2], etc., but you need to tell us exactly what your problem is.  What is wrong?

Comment: I think its better to use a map instead, if you are allowed to use one.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if there are other bugs but you're iterating `b` from 0 to 26 both inclusive and use it as index for the `count[]` of length 26. This array has valid indexes from 0 to 25 both inclusive and you'll receive `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when accessing it with 26.

It should be:

```
...
for (int b = 0; b < 26; b++) 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer since we don't know what's going on.
But here's something, your int[] count array has 26 indices but you're counting to 27:
for (int b = 0; b <= 26; i++) -> This wil result in 27 indices.
Try it with this:

```
public int[] countLetters() {
    int[] count = new int[26];
    char current;

    for (int b = 0; b < 26; b++) {
        for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++) {
            char a = (char) i;
            for (int ch = 0; ch < charArray.length; ch++) {
                current = charArray[ch];
                if (current == a) {
                    count[b]++;
                }
             }
         }
     }
    return count;
}
```

Small error, thanks Fabian

Comment: Java-Arrays are 0-based. Your code will access the array of length 26 with index 26. This results in IndexOutOfBoundsException. Valid indexes are 0-25 for a 26-sized array.

Comment: It still didn't work. Basically the program creates an array (charArray) of random characters. I am trying to count the occurrence of different characters and store the results in an array called count. The first element in the array stores the number of occurrences of 'a' and so on.  Every time the array count prints it keeps on saying there is 0 occurrences for each character. That is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

This is the file charCounter.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class charCounter
{
    char[] charArray = new char[50];
    int randInt;
    Random r = new Random();

    public charCounter()
    {}

    public void create ()
    {
            for (int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++)
        {
                randInt = 97+r.nextInt(26);
                charArray[i] = (char) randInt; //casts these integers as characters
            }
    }

    public void printCharArray()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++)
        {
                System.out.println(charArray[i]);
        }
    }

    public int[] countLetters() 
    {
        int[] count = new int[26];
        int index = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++)
        {
            index = ((int)charArray[i])-97;
            count[index]++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

And here is the driver program I made:

```
public class driver
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        charCounter c = new charCounter();
        int[] printThis;

        c.create();
        printThis = c.countLetters();

        for(int i=0; i<printThis.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(printThis[i]);
        }
    }
}
```